# Problemas para enviar muitas variáveis por _GET

Tags: php

Peço desculpas se eu estiver refazendo esta pergunta, eu procurei muito e não achei nada do tipo.

Meu problema é que eu tenho que enviar muitas variáveis usando `$_GET` usando duas páginas

o código seguinte é da `pagina-cadastro.php`

```
if($_GET['v1'] != '' || ($_GET['v2'] != '') || ($_GET['v3'] != '') || ($_GET['v4'] != '') || ($_GET['v5'] != '') || ($_GET['v6'] != '') || ($_GET['v7'] != '') || 
        ($_GET['v8'] != '') || ($_GET['v9'] != '') || ($_GET['v10'] != '')

$razaoSocial = $_GET['v1'];
        $nomeFantasia = $_GET['v2'];
        $cnpj = $_GET['v3'];
        $email = $_GET['v4'];
        $inscrEstadual = $_GET['v5'];
        $inscrMunicipal = $_GET['v6'];
        $cep = $_GET['v7'];
        $rua = $_GET['v8'];
        $numero = $_GET['v9'];
        $complemento = $_GET['v10'];
    } else {
        $razaoSocial = "";
        $nomeFantasia = "";
        $cnpj = "";
        $email = "";
        $inscrEstadual = "";
        $inscrMunicipal = "";
        $cep = "";
        $rua = "";
        $numero = "";
        $complemento = "";
```

e da página `cadastrar.php` é

```
"<script> window.location = 'pagina-cadastro.php?&v1=".$razaoSocial."&v2=".$nomeFantasia . "&v3=".$cnpj . "&v4=". $email ."&v5=". $inscrEstadual . "&v6=".$inscrMunicipal . "&v7=" .$cep . "&v8=" .$rua . "&v9=" .$numero . "&v10=" .$complemento
```

Eu postei apenas 10 variáveis, mas tenho que fazer 150. Como posso otimizar meu tempo para não escrever uma por uma?

Comment: Você precisa deixar estas variáveis com estes nomes (`v1, v2...`)? Não poderia colocar um nome mais informativo?

Comment: Requisições GET tem um limite máximo de caracteres. Com esses nomes curtos **mais** os valores e os conectores (?, = e &) **mais** domínio, *path* e etc. surpresa seria se funcionasse. @LuizFernandoSanches, existe algum motivo para não fazer via POST?

Comment: Tem ali uma gralha no código, falta a chaveta `{` de abrir o `if`.

Comment: Como o @BrunoAugusto Augusto já comentou, qual a necessidade de utilizar GET e não POST?

Comment: Encontrei uma solução melhor para meu problema, vou validar os campos com javascript e só liberar o botão qdo as informações estiverem corretas, por causa da performance, agradeço a todos que prontamente me ajudaram, muito obrigado

Comment: @LuizFernandoSanches mesmo que você faça isso com javascript você **deve** fazer o mesmo no servidor, no seu caso em php, pois não se deve confiar no que o cliente envia, alguém pode modificar a requisição e enviar qualquer informação no lugar

Answer (score 1):

Daria para fazer algo assim:

```
// coloque todos os valores necessários no array
$arr = array(
        'v2' => 'nomeFantasia',
        'v3' => 'cnpj'
    );

// percorre o array
foreach ($arr as $get => $nome) {
    // verifica se existe o índice desejado no
    // array $_GET e se é diferente de ''
    if (isset($_GET[$get]) && $_GET[$get] != '') {
        // seta a variável com o valor correto
        $$nome = $_GET[$get];

        // pesquise sobre variáveis variáveis
        // http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php
    } else {
        $$nome = '';
    }
}
```

Mas acredito que você deva rever sua lógica. Se você está colocando os valores em variáveis desta forma, significa que irá utilizar todas manualmente novamente. Seu código deverá ficar extremamente grande e confuso.

Procure por tutoriais de php e veja o código de outras pessoas. Muito conhecimento pode ser adquirido desta forma.

Answer (score 0):

No lado do cliente basta enviar com um botão submit que todos os dados do form serão enviados

Exp:

```
<form id="frmCad" name="frmCad" method="get" action="suapag.php">

<input type="text" id="1" name="1">
<input type="text" id="2" name="2">
<input type="text" id="3" name="3">
<input type="text" id="4" name="4">
<input type="text" id="5" name="5">
<input type="text" id="6" name="6">

<input id="cmdSalvar" name="cmdSalvar" type="submit" value="Salvar">

</form>
```

Como são muitos campos, recomendo a utilização do `POST`, em vez de `GET`, senão a url da página que recebe os dados irá ficar MUITO grande...

Se você quiser fazer algo mais sofisticado enviando via Ajax, ou JSON, basta `serializar` todos os campos....

Utilizando a biblioteca `Jquery`

Exp:

```
$("frmCad").submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Depende da sua real necessidade, eu opto muitas vezes por fazer um formulário simples e enviar o formulário de acordo com a primeira opção, somente se houver a necessidade de não poder acontecer um `refresh` na página eu optaria pela segunda, continua sendo simples, porém...

No lado do servidor é só você fazer o tratamento das váriaveis de acordo com a sua necessidade.... e não conheço nenhuma escapatória, no lado do servidor você deve fazer tratamento váriavel por váriavel....

Obs: O que o @Oeslei comentou é importante, geralmente é bom dar um nome real pra váriavel, e deixar documentado, isso facilita em muito futuras manutenções de código, as vezes da trabalho e cansa, mas é o mais recomendável e faz parte de boas práticas de programação...

Exp: variavel `CursoEscolhido`, tente abreviar o máx possivel a ponte de ser entendível por qualquer pessoa que depois vá abrir seu código e fazer uma manutenção, `curEsco` por exemplo

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com o que o Nelson disse, faça algo parecido com isto:

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_aqui');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->access_token;
```

Para que isso funcione, file_get_contents requer que allow_url_fopen esteja ativado. Se não der certo, você pode apenas usar curl para obter a url:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

PORÉM EU CREIO QUE NÃO SEJA ESTE O SEU PROBLEMA. Você quer automatizar a sua requisição GET de forma que diminua o seu trabalho na colocação de mais de 50 variáveis? Cara, a sua lógica é linear, ela requer que você escreva algo sequencial. Por isso, você não pode criar um outro tipo de lógica, que retire este seu trabalho de escrever 100 variáveis. Eu acredito que não há solução para o que você quer.

Answer (score -1):

Quando você vê que está a começar a usar muitas variáveis para apenas armazenar valores, o melhor é passar tudo para um `array`.

Mas quanto ao seu código, as condições que está a usar são redundantes por isso pode logo passar para a construção do script da seguinte maneira:

```
<script>
window.location = 'pagina-cadastro.php?
<?php
    foreach($_GET as $key => $val){
        echo $key."=".$val."&";
    }
?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Primeiro no cliente usando javascript passe todo o form todo em formato json para o PHP e depois no servidor, primeiro decodifique o json e depois faça um parse do resultado.